# can you call a function while loading data in D3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to figure out if there is a way I can call a function while loading data in D3.js.   My code is below, I am not sure if I am on the right track, it seems so simple but I cant get it to work

```
d3.json("Country_data.json", mac.call(Country_data));


function mac(e) {

//I  would like for this function to perform some operations.
//The data in the file Country_data is passed to this function
}
```

If anyone had ideas on how I can implement this I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is passing the result of calling `mac()` where it should be passing a reference to `mac` like so...

```
d3.json("Country_data.json", mac);

function mac(error, countryData) {
  if (error) {
    // deal with error
  } else {
    // perform some operations on countryData
  }
}
```

or declare the callback as an anonymous function inline with the call to d3.json:

```
d3.json("Country_data.json", function (error, countryData) {
  if (error) {
    // deal with error
  } else {
    // perform some operations on countryData
  }
});
```